# Bootstrap thumbnail carousel compresses from two lines to one

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using the code at http://www.bootply.com/81478

and attempting to layer the effect at http://www.bootply.com/pZ5o0OgHxp

Why does the slider start off 'ok' and eventually run into a single line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made it more complex than it needs to be.  If you want 2 rows just make them both inside a single "item" as follows:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
     <!-- Carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                </div>
                <!--/carousel-inner--> 
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
            </div>
            <!--/myCarousel-->
```

In case you're curious why you're approach didn't work, it's actually simple:  the carousel js adds an active class to the element with the .item class to display.  You have the "active" present in your markup like you should, so the js runs through the first time, adding it to each subsequent .item element.  However, when it reaches the last item grouping, the code looks for the first element with the .item class inside the .carousel-inner and adds to that item.  In your case, that means it only will add the class to the single row.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're missing the JS code and CSS, you need to add both of them in order to make the carousel work

Comment: You are correct there is no JS or CSS included... 

This is not the reason it doesnt work. - include the jquery yourself and see. the CSS appears to be pure styling.

Comment: have you a link - i mean ive had it in, out, in and then out - not working so i tried to provide a simple example

Comment: breaks on the 4th click like mine.

Comment: you should make better questions. I was answering why your carousel wasn't working at all. Anyway, the problem you mention is really simple. You're using 250px by 250px images in your first 3 lists, then you use a 500px (scaled to 277px) image, so the layout breaks simply because you're using different sizes. Either use always the same size or restrain the size of elements, like max-height or max-width (whatever you need)

Comment: i agree that your comments are entirely logical.

this http://www.bootply.com/13k6mFHGFh# - demonstrates that its not the answer though

The carousel was working and i ask why it 'runs into a single line' its clear to anyone that looks at the link that im asking why it breaks.

Comment: I really don't understand your question or what do you want to achieve. If you want JUST ONE ROW, you need to take off that additional slider you have added and causes the 2 rows which transforms in 1 because once you have passed all the next/prev slides, the script gets back to initial state. If yo want 2 different sliders, you need to have them with 2 different IDs, not 2 inner-slides inside the same ID. If you want 2 rows, you need to duplicate the rows inside the .item element. Again, have no idea what do you want to do, but I assume it has to be one of these options